# Get Where with substr in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Hello Sir I want to search use collect (Where) in laravel

```
2 => array:13 [▶]
3 => array:13 [▼
  ".id" => "*15E"
  "name" => "yuliano"
  "password" => "panji123"
  "profile" => "voucher2menit"
  "limit-bytes-out" => "104857600"
  "uptime" => "0s"
  "bytes-in" => "0"
  "bytes-out" => "0"
  "packets-in" => "0"
  "packets-out" => "0"
  "dynamic" => "false"
  "disabled" => "false"
  "comment" => "jan/14/2022 00:18:53 up"
]
```

i want to get data is only "UP"

$response2 = $query->Where("comment", substr(-2) == "vc");

please help me sir

Comment: you have a Collection you want to use `where` with or you are building a query and you want to use `where`?

Comment: i have query in api but i want to get query "up" because there 2 query different "comment" => "jan/14/2022 00:18:53 up" and "comment" => "jan/14/2022 00:18:53 vc"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **LIKE** operator.

Here is an example:

```
$users = DB::table('users')
            ->where('name', 'LIKE', 'John%')
            ->get();
```

It will get any user with name that starts as "John".

If you want to get any record that ends with "John", you need to change the % string position:

```
    $users = DB::table('users')
            ->where('name', 'LIKE', '%John')
            ->get();
```

Also, if you want to get any record that has "John" word in any part of it, you could use "%John%", like that:

```
$users = DB::table('users')
            ->where('name', 'LIKE', '%John%')
            ->get();
```

In your case, you could do something like this:

```
$response2 = $query->where("comment", "LIKE", "%up")->get();
```

Checkout the docs

- [Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#where-clauses)
- [W3SCHOOLS](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp)
- [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/pattern-matching.html)

Comment: thanks to respon my question sir, but is not work sir, i have query in api but i want to get query "up" because there 2 query different "comment" => "jan/14/2022 00:18:53 up" and "comment" => "jan/14/2022 00:18:53 vc"

Comment: It should have worked. Any error was displayed?